# while ( mysqli_fetch_array() ) returns only 1 result when there are more

Tags: php, mysql

I just started learning PHP for an assignment I have to do for school.

I have a problem with the mysqli_fetch_array() function.

Here is my code:

```
//Find all book_id for a specific student_id
$query = " SELECT * FROM books_of_students WHERE student_id = '$s_id' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query); 
$records_b_o_s = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

If I echo the variable $records_b_o_s it correctly shows how many records MySql has returned from the table, here is a screenshot from phpMyAdmin:

[books_of_students table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8EnR.png)

Here is the following part of my code:

```
if ($records_b_o_s >= 1) {

    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
       $temp_book_id = $row['book_id'];
       //do other stuff
    }

}
```

The problem is that the loop only occurs 1 time and $row['book_id'] returns the value from the first book there is in "books_of_students" table. If for example I execute the following command inside the loop:

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
       $temp_book_id = $row['book_id'];
       echo "Current book_id: " . $temp_book_id . "<br>"; //<---This one
       //do other stuff
}
```

There will be only 1 message and it will show only the first book_id from the table

I really don't know what to do here so I will much appreciate your help! Thanks in advance :)

Comment: They should have taught you prepared statements.  Helps to have a good foundation

Comment: what's the value of `$s_id` that you're passing through that query?

Comment: Try `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()` and use `if ($records_b_o_s > 1)` removing the `=`. You're checking if it's also equal to 1.

Comment: You asked for help, I asked for clarification and will not be helping any more than I already have. If you left the question, then that doesn't help you. Good luck, I won't be looking at this question any further waiting on a response.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for your time and your answers!

It turned out that I had done something stupid within the while() loop. At some point I was changing the value of the $result variable without noticing it! Now the code works as it should be!